# Is the foreach binding syntax valid

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When I read the documentation for BindingContext on KnockoutJS [website](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html), it has an code example like below to illustrate $data:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: ['cats', 'dogs', 'fish']">
    <li>The value is <span data-bind="text: $data"></span></li>
</ul>
```

I am pretty new to KnockoutJS, I wonder is putting a direct array after foreach binding a valid usage? And also in above case, it seems you can omit using applyBinding() to activate. So I guess such syntax is only for illustration purpose, it is not a valid code like what could be in a real KnockoutJS application.

If someone has had similar thoughts and is assured, could you either confirm or correct me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question 
'I wonder is putting a direct array after foreach binding a valid usage? '

Yes it is just for illustration purpose they have put the code there. And if you put the code in sinppet code will not work because

1. They do not want to illustrate foreach here in fact they are giving example of $data.
2. For foreach documentation take alook [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

To another your another question 
'it seems you can omit using applyBinding() to activate'

No you cannot omit the applyBinding.

Look in following sinnpet code will not give you desired output unless add ko.applybinding in your code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'etc' ]">
    <li>
        The current item is: <b data-bind="text: $data"></b>
    </li>
</ul>
 

<script type="text/javascript">
    //ko.applyBindings();
</script>
```

As quoted in Knockout documentation

> Activating Knockout
>
> The data-bind attribute isn’t native to HTML, though it is perfectly
>   OK (it’s strictly compliant in HTML 5, and causes no problems with
>   HTML 4 even though a validator will point out that it’s an
>   unrecognized attribute). But since the browser doesn’t know what it
>   means, you need to activate Knockout to make it take effect.
>
> To activate Knockout, add the following line to a <script> block:
>
> ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);